# Not able to install ROSARIA on Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, rosaria, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit
ROS: Fuerte

I tried following the ROSARIA tutorial on ROS Wiki.

The step where it tells you to use "roslocate info ROSARIA" does not work for me.

Then I use the command given below (on Fuerte):

```
$rosws set amor-ros-pkg https:_//code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/ --hg
$rosws update amor-ros-pkg
```

It creates a package "amor-ros-pkg". But I am not able to find the package using rospack command:

```
$rospack find ROSARIA
[rospack] Error: stack/package ROSARIA not found
```

However this folder is already in the ros package path:

```
$echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/swagat/ros_workspace/amor-ros-pkg:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

so basically I can not proceed further until I fix these problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57989/not-able-to-install-rosaria-on-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts?/) by [swagatk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4401/swagatk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swagatk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4401/swagatk/) on 2013-03-12**:
remove the underscore in the beginning of URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Try specifying the fuerte branch of rosaria manually:

rosws set amor-ros-pkg https://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/ --hg -v fuerte

then use rosws update, and confirm changes and follow instructions printed to update.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swagatk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4401/swagatk/) on 2013-03-25**:
This worked for me and thanks for updating the tutorial :(http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA). I am now able to build ROSARIA Package. Thanks for the help.